# Delegate called multiple times from asynchronous WCF method

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates

In a client application, I am using an asynchronous WCF method being called from the following code:

```
 public void doActiveDx()
    {
        this.dataservice.GetActiveDxCompleted += (s,e) =>
        {
          ...do something...                
        };
        this.dataservice.GetActiveDxAsync( );
    }
```

Why is the delegate called multiple times when doActiveDx() is called but once?

In my case, ...do something..., is updating an observable collection bound to the display, so having the delegate called multiple times is causing a flickering effect on the display.

How can I have the delegate called but once on completion of doActiveDx() ???

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a call to `doActiveDx` is performed, the delegate is registered once again. This results in multiple calls to the delegate on subsequent calls to `doActiveDx`.

Make sure you are registering the delegate just once. For instance, try registering it outside the `doActiveDx` function.

Comment: Alternatively you unregister each time, that way you are less likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

@Thiago-Sá is correct about the issue you encountered. I will now give you some hints on how to fix it.

If possible, make `GetActiveDxAsync()` return a `Task`. Then you can add a [continuation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) with your delegate, as follow:

```
this.dataservice.GetActiveDxAsync()
    .ContinueWith(() =>
    {
        // do something
    };
```

You could also use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) if you are using .Net 4.5 and C# 5 (provided that a task is return like in the first point):

```
await this.dataservice.GetActiveDxAsync();
// do something after the completion
```

Other remark: in my own implementation of WCF service, I often use a proxy on the client side. This proxy inherits from [ClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx) and is created each time I need to make a call. So I often end up with code looking like the following:

```
var proxy = new DataServiceProxy();
proxy.GetActiveDxCompleted += (s,e) =>
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    finally
    {
        proxy.Close();
    }                
};
proxy.GetActiveDxAsync();
```

This means that since it is a new instance each time you won't have multiple calls.